# Start a thread within the class constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

Can a Thread class self-start from the class constructor using `self.start()`?

Currently, a class that inherits from the Thread object needs to be started using .start()

```
my_thread = ThreadClass()
my_thread.start()
```

Can I move the start method to be called within the `ThreadClass.__init__` method? That way, whenever the class is instantiated, the thread is automatically started.

Comment: Yes, it works. I'm not sure why its not the default. You need to call `super().__init__` first.

Comment: is it ok to do that? or not recommended?

Comment: If it was the default, then the thread would start as soon `super().__init__` was called, not giving you a chance to further initialize your subclass's object before the thread starts.